# OnItemClickListener in Fragment with CustomAdapter doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

like described in the title I try to use an OnItemClickListener in a Fragment (It does NOT extend ListFragment, it is just a Fragment) but the Listener does not seem to respond.

How does it work:
I created a Fragment which contains a ListView with custom ListViewItem, the content is downloaded from a mysql table with a class called Downloader connected to PHP files and a class called Parser which translates the given JSON result into Strings. There is a CustomAdapter who takes the result and changes the TextViews of the custom ListViewItem with the results of the Parser.

The ListView is created without problems, the content gets displayed. 
**Fragment Code:**

```
public class BiologyFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {


String url = "URL FOR PHP - just cut that out :D";
private SwipeRefreshLayout ll;
private ListView lv;
private boolean isRefreshing;
private Handler refreshhandler = new Handler();

public BiologyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ll = (SwipeRefreshLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biology, container, false);

    //set up listener for pull to refresh
    ll.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    //Listview for the to be populated
    lv = (ListView) ll.findViewById(R.id.lv);

    //download on opening
    new Downloader(getContext(), url, lv).execute();

    //PROBLEM HERE !
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CLICKED " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            boolean enable = false;

            if (lv != null && lv.getChildCount() > 0) {
                // check if the first item of the list is visible
                boolean firstItemVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
                // check if the top of the first item is visible
                boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = lv.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
                // enabling or disabling the refresh layout
                enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
            }
            ll.setEnabled(enable);
        }

    });

    return ll;
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Downloader(getContext(), url, lv).execute();
    refreshhandler.post(refreshing);
}

Runnable refreshing = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(isRefreshing){
            // re run the verification after 1 second
        }else{
            // stop the animation after the data is fully loaded
            ll.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
};


}
```

**The XML of the Fragment:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        />



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow" />

</FrameLayout>
```

If you need the ListViewItem XML or the CustomAdapter, the Downloader or Parser Class just let me know and I will post it here, I am just not sure if these are necessary to solve the problem.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

You **shouldn't** convert your root to `SwipeRefreshLayout` so Instead of using:

```
 ll = (SwipeRefreshLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biology, container, false);
```

use:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biology, container, false);
lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CLICKED " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Also you don't use `SweapRefreshLayout` properly it's recommend to do this:

```
<!-- rest of layout -->

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView">

    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<!-- rest of layout-->
```

Comment: That does not seem to work
"Requires android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
Found android.view.View"

Comment: Your Code does work without errors, though I cannot refresh anymore, when I try the circle keeps on being there without doing anything. Also it does not fix my problem with the onItemClickListener :/

Comment: @JustinN you should set setOnRefreshListener for swipeRefreshLayout and in listener handle this. it's also work for onClickListener it's just a simple code to give you idea how your code should be it may be need some modification.

Comment: I found out that actually I just gotta set an OnItemClickListener while the adapter is set so I put an OnItemClickListener into Parser and it worked out well ^^